# Where are all the shops located?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

So far I have only found the hobo which doesn't sell anything high level and the starting store in Kyle's backyard which only sells up to level 10 gear IIRC.

Is there going to be another store for 11+ items?

Comment: Most equipment you find during the main quests of the game, you don't buy them. But yes, there are additional store in the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**List of locations to buy stuff:**

- Elven Kingdom shop
- Girl's Hideout shop
- Purchase from Mr. Mackey
- Purchase from Hobo outside U-Stor-It
- Kupa Keep shop
- Banff shop
- Vancouver Shop
- Jimbo's Gun Store
- Ottawa Shop
- Winnipeg Shop

[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/south-park-the-stick-of-truth/Weapons_and_Costume_Sets)